# Accessing nested ids in Queryset Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

how can i access the category_id? I want to create a list of similar products based on category. So each time i make a get request f.e products/1052/similarproducts, i want to get all the ProductsInStore of the same category as ProductInStore(id=1052) and exclude the ProductInStore(id=1052), my current code gives me "ecommerce.models.ProductInStore.DoesNotExist: ProductInStore matching query does not exist."
Even though a productInStore of 1052 exists.

```
class ProductInStore(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_category = models.ManyToManyField(EcommerceProductCategory)
```

```
class SimilarProductsListApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = ProductInStore.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductInStoreSerializer

    #products/954/similarproductsr

    def get_queryset(self):
        product_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        category = ProductInStore.objects.values_list('product__product_category', flat=True).get(product_id=product_id)
        return ProductInStore.objects.filter(product__product_category=category).exclude(product_id=product_id).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your product_id were id of ProductInStore instance, not Product instance and because their ids most likely vary, you could not get instance

```
class SimilarProductsListApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = ProductInStore.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductInStoreSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        product_in_store_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        category = ProductInStore.objects.get(id=product_in_store_id).product.product_category
        return ProductInStore.objects.filter(product__product_category=category).exclude(id=product_in_store_id)
```

Comment: It worked, but i had to change product__product_category__in and add .all() to category variable because product_category is manytoomany. But thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh yes, i missed that :)